# Scroll list of thumbnails

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I need to allow my users to scroll through a list of thumbnails in the documents directory on an iPad application. When they tap on one of the thumbnails, I need to know which one was tapped (or have it call a method, which is basically the same thing.)

I know how to put the thumbnails in the documents directory, and how to read them from there. But I’m not sure which widget is best for displaying the content. Is it UITableView? CCScrollLayer? CCMenuAdvanced? Something else?

Comment: I'd use UITableView so the cells should reuse themselves and not overhead memory with many UIImages.

Comment: @sp4rkbr can you show a code sample?

Answer (score 0):

`CCScrollLayer` doesn't work as well as `UIScrollView`.

I use the view to `CCdirector` for add `UIkit`.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView alloc] init]; 
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:scrollView];
```

or add `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Take all the paths for thumbnails in one array, lets call pathsArray

`NSArray *pathsArray = [seld getPathsForAllImages];`

Now implement UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [pathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *pathForImage = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForImage];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *pathForImage = [pathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: I mean call this prgramatically, from a cocos2d project.

Comment: I don't know, you didn't mention cocos2d on your question. Sorry.

Comment: Cocos2d is tagged. Don't worry about it, your answer put me in the right direction. If I can implement based on it I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had all kinds of problems with overlaying a UIScrollView on a cocos2d project. Even with all the suggested hacks, if a single frame takes too long in cocos2d, the UIScrollView just stops working right. I would suspect that would happen with a UITableView as well.

To solve my own problems, I created a custom [ScrollNode](https://github.com/levilansing/cocos2d-ScrollNode) class. It's really easy to use:

```
// create the scroll node
ScrollNode *scrollNode = [ScrollNode nodeWithSize:CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height)];
[self addChild:scrollNode];

// Generate some content for the scroll view
// add it directly to scrollView, or to the built in menu (scrollView.menu)
[scrollNode.menu addChild:yourMenuItem];

// Set the content rect to represent the scroll area
CGRect contentRect = [scrollNode calculateScrollViewContentRect];
[scrollNode setScrollViewContentRect:contentRect];
```